# How to use Python Requests to query JSON-formatted data from a REST API?

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to use the Sophos UTM RESTful API to copy some configuration from one device to another. The API is actually Swagger, so this should not be specific to the Sophos device.

The first part of the script queries the source device for a specific node:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

src_URL = 'https://172.16.2.100:4444/api/objects/http/exception'
src_headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic dG9rZW46U2tCaENIZUlRZnlVeEpBU3dqYUh2c0VHRmZjdWtDTFg='
        }
response = requests.get(src_URL, headers=src_headers, timeout=15, verify=False)
```

That part works fine. The script is able to connect to the API and query the data successfully. The returned `status_code` is 200.

Next the script tries to use the returned data from the source device and copy it to the destination device:

```
payload = response.json()

dst_URL = 'https://172.16.2.101:4444/api/objects/http/exception'
dst_headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic dG9rZW46dlZ3WnVZZGxpd01IRkxNVXpKVXZtZXhiZGZHSExobnI='
        }
update =  requests.post(dst_URL, headers=dst_headers, json=payload, timeout=15, verify=False)

result = update.content
print (result)
```

No error is returned but it's not working and the print statement returns this:

```
b'[]'
```

So basically, it seems that the content of `update` is empty, and is a byte for some reason.

Why does the content of `update` is empty? I would expect it to contain the returned data in JSON format.

**EDIT**

OK I think I figured out why it's not working as I expect. The API returns a nested dictionary to the query to the first device.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic dG9rZW46U2tCaENIZUlRZnlVeEpBU3dqYUh2c0VHRmZjdWtDTFg=' 'https://172.16.2.100:4444/api/objects/http/exception/' -k
[
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_FirefoxUpdateException",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Work around Firefox Byte Range-Request Bug",
    "domains": [
      "^http://download\\.cdn\\.mozilla\\.net/.*\\.mar"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Firefox Update",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "av",
      "sandbox",
      "extensions",
      "contenttype_blacklist",
      "check_max_download"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_TrendmicroUpdateException",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Work around problems with Trendmicro product update",
    "domains": [
      "^http://([A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.)?activeupdate\\.trendmicro\\.com(:80)?/"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Trendmicro Update",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "cache",
      "av",
      "sandbox",
      "extensions",
      "contenttype_blacklist",
      "url_filter",
      "content_removal"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_AdobeDownloadException",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Allows Adobe Software Update without content scanning side effects.",
    "domains": [
      "^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.)?adobe\\.com/",
      "^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.)?macromedia\\.com/"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Adobe Software Update",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "av",
      "sandbox",
      "extensions",
      "content_removal",
      "user_auth",
      "url_filter"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_TeamviewerException",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Work around Teamviewer SSL handshake Bug",
    "domains": [
      "^https?://(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+teamviewer\\.com/?"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Teamviewer Remote Access",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "sandbox",
      "ssl_scanning"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_jzpKEIbHnW",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Allows Windows Update without content scanning side effects.",
    "domains": [
      "^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.)?windowsupdate\\.com/",
      "^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.)?microsoft\\.com/"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Microsoft Windows Update",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "av",
      "sandbox",
      "extensions",
      "ssl_scanning",
      "check_max_download"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_EppBrokerCommunicationException",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Allow endpoints to connect to Sophos LiveConnect",
    "domains": [
      "^https?://mcs[0-9]*-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}\\.broker\\.sophos\\.com/",
      "^https?://mcs[0-9]*-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-d\\.broker\\.sophos\\.com/",
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*-wdx-[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.broker\\.sophos\\.com/",
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.upe\\.p\\.hmr\\.sophos\\.com/",
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.hydra\\.sophos\\.com/",
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.cwg\\.sophos\\.com/",
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.mojave\\.net/"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Sophos LiveConnect",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "user_auth",
      "cache",
      "av",
      "sandbox",
      "extensions",
      "contenttype_blacklist",
      "url_filter",
      "content_removal",
      "ssl_scanning",
      "certcheck",
      "certdate",
      "check_max_download"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_NokiaOviSuiteException",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Work around Nokia Ovi Suite Authentication Bug",
    "domains": [
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.ovi\\.com/",
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*nds[0-9]\\.nokia\\.com/",
      "^https?://beta\\.nokia\\.com/"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Nokia Ovi Suite/Store",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "user_auth",
      "av",
      "sandbox"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_SophosServicesException",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Allow Sophos Services",
    "domains": [
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.sophosupd\\.com/",
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.sophosupd\\.net/",
      "^https?://[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.sophosxl\\.net/"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Sophos Services",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "user_auth",
      "av",
      "sandbox",
      "extensions",
      "contenttype_blacklist",
      "url_filter",
      "content_removal",
      "ssl_scanning",
      "certcheck",
      "certdate",
      "check_max_download"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_ChromeUpdateException",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Work around Chrome Byte Range-Request Bug",
    "domains": [
      "^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.google\\.com\\/)(([A-Za-z0-9.-\\/]+)?)[0-9._]*chrome_(updater|installer)\\.exe"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Chrome Update",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "av",
      "sandbox",
      "extensions",
      "contenttype_blacklist",
      "check_max_download"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_iPhoneiPadYoutubeException",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Work around iPad/Iphone Byterange Bug",
    "domains": [
      "^http://[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.googlevideo\\.com/videoplayback",
      "^http://[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.youtube\\.com/videoplayback"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "iphone/iPad youtube",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "av",
      "sandbox",
      "contenttype_blacklist",
      "content_removal",
      "check_max_download"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  },
  {
    "_locked": "",
    "_ref": "REF_jzpKEIbHnX",
    "_type": "http/exception",
    "aaa": [],
    "comment": "Allows Apple Update without content scanning side effects.",
    "domains": [
      "^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.)?apple\\.com\\.?/"
    ],
    "endpoints_groups": [],
    "name": "Apple Update",
    "networks": [],
    "operator": "OR",
    "skiplist": [
      "av",
      "sandbox",
      "extensions"
    ],
    "sp_categories": [],
    "status": true,
    "tags": [],
    "user_agents": []
  }
```

I am unsure if the API accepts that kind of data using a `POST` or if it is not formatted properly.

Would it be a good idea to segment the nested dictionary (wouldn't know how though) into single dictionary and looping through each of them using a `for` loop?

Otherwise, the data needs to be formatted some other way but I don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

If the content being returned is json, requests provides a `json` utility method you can use to retrieve the data: `update = update.json()`

See [Requests docs](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) for more info

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. Is this not the same thing as I am doing (payload = repsonse.json())?

Comment: OK sorry I get what you mean. The content of `update` is `[]`, so basically empty. Any guess why that is?

Comment: I would take a look at what that endpoint (`/api/http/exception`) to make sure your params, headers, payload is correct because returning an empty list may be a valid response for this specific endpoint.

Comment: OK, I think I figured out why it's not working as I want it to. The request to the source device returns a nested dictionary. I am unsure if the API accepts that or if it's simply not formated properly. I will edit my original post so you can see what is returned. Maybe we can find a way to format it so that it is accepted by the API. Thanks again!